# WriteLineAsync Not Work With Analyze Code Coverage in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have a unit test containing `streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(outputLine)`

The part of the code is shown below:

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string name = string.Empty;
        while ((name = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var result = this.entitySatoriIDAccessor.GetEntityAndSatoriId(name);
            foreach (Tuple<string, string, string, double> tuple in result)
            {
                string outputLine = string.Format(
                  "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
                  tuple.Item1,
                  tuple.Item2,
                  tuple.Item3,
                  tuple.Item4);
                streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(outputLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The unit test could run through with "Run Selected Test" from VS, but if I select `"Analyze Code Coverage For Selected Tests"`, then the test would fail with error message `"The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream"`. I'm wondering why this happens, any special setting with Analyze Code Coverage in VS?

Comment: it seems you are using streamReader object in while loop. did you try closing the streamReader object and see error disappears?

Comment: I'm reading each line from the reader, processing the line and writing the result to another  file asynchronously. will that be a problem?